# Can we use meta:resourcekey for CssClass attribute in ASP.NET 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, .net, resources

I am using `meta:Resourcekey` for displaying text in different languages using the resource file.

For example:

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltStatus" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="alertsStatus" />
```

Now can I use the same approach for `CssClass` attribute? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works the same as the `Text` property works. If for the `Text` property you create a resource entry with the name `alertsStatus.Text` then for the `CssClass` you need to have one with the name `alertsStatus.CssClass` and provide the appropriate class name to be used according to the resource culture.

When you use the `meta:resourcekey="CustomPrefix"` you are enabling implicit resource expression for that control, so you can basically set all the available properties in the control through the local resources using the format `CustomPrefix.PropertyName`.

Comment: Strangely, in this case the `CssClass` attribute in the tag overrides the `alertsStatus.CssClass` resource (at least in ASP.Net 4.0), which is the opposite of what happens with the `Text` property.